# Project Componements disappeared in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and this morning the Project Components in my project disappeared. That is in the toolbox, I cannot add any more objects from the classes I defined. And I have errors for the existing elements using theses classes: there are not defined.

Here is how it looked before and after. The first Component Category is now gone.

[image: Before and after that the Project Components disappeared]

My main problem comes from the *PageControl* element. I now have the error "The type "Wolf_Calc.PageControl" could not be found."

Where could this come from?

I suspect the problem to come from DropBox that I use to sync and backup my project files. Some errors appeared with non-ASCII names, such as *Gebäude.vb* being rename *Geb"ude.vb*... But all characters in the *PageControl* Component are ASCII (not true for the other components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I tried the accepted answer of [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090674/new-to-c-sharp-the-type-or-namespace-cannot-be-found).

For whatever reason could Visual Studio not find the class definition. But moving the class into the main program and compiling it solved my problem.